# SharePoint Online API - Get List Items returns no results

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Been trying to query a very simple list on my SPO tenant and the response always comes back successful but with no results. I have another list in the same SPO site that I can query and I do get results back from that one (that one was created quite some time ago). I've looked everywhere for permissions settings that might not allow others to see the list items, but as far as I can tell, it is set up exactly like the list that works. I'm hitting this URL after authenticating (authentication works fine - using the accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net method for that, as I'm doing all of this in a REST client to test):

[https://mytenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/MySPOSiteName/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyListName')/items](https://mytenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/MySPOSiteName/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(%27MyListName%27)/items)

Any reason why, in the same SPO site and with both lists using the same permissions, that one list would return results and the other would not? I have also checked to make sure neither list requires approvals for the list items to be available.

Answer (score 0):

To get list items from SharePoint list, try using REST endpoint in this format with `/items`:

```
https://mytenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/MySPOSiteName/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Display Name of List')/items
```

**Documentation**: [Working with lists and list items with REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest)

Comment: That's what I did (looks like I forgot to include the /items in my original post). Still returns zero results.

Comment: Can you try hitting this URL directly in browser tab and see if it returns any results or error: `https://mytenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/MySPOSiteName/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Display Name of List')/items?$select=ID,Title`

Comment: Since the API requires auth, I get an "unauthorized" when I just hit that in the browser. As stated in the post, the previous requests to get the auth token and then the request itself return successfully, but just show zero results (when there are definitely list items in the list).

Comment: to test the api in browser you should first log into the site this should store auth cookie for the session then you can open another tab and make the api call. And also double check if list is configured with item level permissions.